# I am creating a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I want a structure like

```
var={userid:{bookid:rating,book2:rating,.....}}
```

I am not getting how to query it.
I am getting a structure like this:-
example:-

```
var={1:{101:2}}{1:{102:1}}
```

but I want

```
var={1:{101:2,102:1}}
```

I am fetching all the values of `userid,bookid,ratings` from database.
And also I would like to know how to access those records

Actually I am creating a recommender engine so I need to compare each user with every other user.Please if anyone can help me in this
Thankyou

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. You question must clearly display the question, the data, the expected output, and what you have attempted in a structured manner. Please restructure your question so that we can help you properly.

Comment: That aren't Python dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry.I want output as var={userid:{bookid:rating,book2:rating,.....}}All the values of userid,bookid,ratings are to be fetched from database in python.What structure other than dictionary can I use for this purpose??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question on how to create such a structure. You can create a dictionary like this one by following lines:

```
a = {}
a[1] = {}
a[1][101] = 2
a[1][102] = 1
print a  # output: {1: {101: 2, 102: 1}}
```

(It's actually a dictionary in a dictionary)

To answer your question how to access the results:
Here is a code example for accessing the results of your query.

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees "
         "WHERE hire_date BETWEEN %s AND %s")

hire_start = datetime.date(1999, 1, 1)
hire_end = datetime.date(1999, 12, 31)

cursor.execute(query, (hire_start, hire_end))

for (first_name, last_name, hire_date) in cursor:
  print("{}, {} was hired on {:%d %b %Y}".format(
    last_name, first_name, hire_date))

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

(This example is taken from this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

This could be helpful as well: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Yes  but I want to fetch data from database.will it work for data that will be directly fetched from database?

Comment: Umm, did you try it? I have no clue what your using to handle your database, so I can't tell if it works. how do you fetch the data from the database? Do you use SQLAlchemy? What kind of database do you use? It would help, if you would show more code and explain more.

Comment: Yes I tried it.It is not giving me the desired output.I am using mysql.

Comment: Yes I tried it.It is not giving me the desired output.I am using mysql.  code` sql = "SELECT  * from user_reccomendation"
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in results:
    a[row[0]]={}
    a[row[0]][row[1]]=row[2]
   print a`                                                                                                 This is what I have done.  What changes I should make then??In user_reccomendation table I have userid,bookid,ratings columns.@JonnyTieM

Comment: You should update your question with the infos in your comment. It has better formatting and everyone sees it. The chance is higher that you will find someone to help you then.

Comment: Yes the solution you gave worked for me.I made a few changes and it worked for fetching values from database.Thankyou @JonnyTieM

Comment: Your welcome. I'm happy I could help you. When an answer helped you solve the problem you should accept it, to show other users that this answer solved your problem. You can do that by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer.